How to send the requests to IMAP server via proxy?
I'm trying to connect to IMAP through the proxy with modules aioimaplib and python-socks.
I tried to overwrite create_connection method like this:
import asyncio
import ssl

from aioimaplib.aioimaplib import (
    IMAP4,
    IMAP4ClientProtocol
)
from python_socks.async_.asyncio import Proxy
from python_socks._errors import ProxyConnectionError, ProxyError, ProxyTimeoutError
from python_socks._types import ProxyType
from verboselogs import VerboseLogger

from .exceptions import EmailProxyError
from src.schemas import ProxyStructure


class ImapProxyClient(IMAP4):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        host: str,
        port: int,
        timeout: float = 30,
        ssl_context: ssl.SSLContext | None = None,
        proxy: ProxyStructure | None = None
    ):
        self._ssl_context = ssl_context
        self._proxy = proxy
        self._charset = 'utf-8'

        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout
        self._idle_waiter = None

    @property
    def sock_type(self) -> ProxyType | None:
        if not hasattr(self, '_sock_type'):
            if self._proxy is None:
                self._sock_type = None
            else:
                protos = {
                    'http': ProxyType.HTTP,
                    'socks4': ProxyType.SOCKS4,
                    'socks5': ProxyType.SOCKS5
                }
                self._sock_type = protos.get(self._proxy.proto.lower())
        return self._sock_type

    async def create_client(self) -> None:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self.protocol = IMAP4ClientProtocol(loop)
        if self._proxy and self.sock_type:
            proxy = Proxy(
                proxy_type=self.sock_type,
                host=self._proxy.host,
                port=self._proxy.port,
                username=self._proxy.username, # type: ignore
                password=self._proxy.password # type: ignore
            )
            try:
                sock = await proxy.connect(self.host, self.port, timeout=self.timeout)
            except (ProxyError, ProxyConnectionError, ProxyTimeoutError):
                raise EmailProxyError('Failed to connect to IMAP')
            task = asyncio.create_task(loop.create_connection(
                lambda: self.protocol,
                ssl=self._ssl_context,
                server_hostname=self.host if self._ssl_context else None,
                sock=sock
            ))
        else:
            task = asyncio.create_task(loop.create_connection(
                lambda: self.protocol,
                self.host,
                self.port,
                ssl=self._ssl_context,
            ))


class ImapSslProxyClient(ImapProxyClient):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        host: str,
        port: int,
        timeout: float = 30,
        ssl_context: ssl.SSLContext | None = None,
        proxy: ProxyStructure | None = None
    ):
        if ssl_context is None:
            ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
        super().__init__(
            host=host,
            port=port,
            timeout=timeout,
            ssl_context=ssl_context,
            proxy=proxy
        )

This is a sample of test:
client = ImapSslProxyClient(host=host, port=port, timeout=timeout, proxy=proxy)
await client.create_client()
await client.wait_hello_from_server() # Establish a connection
await client.login(user, password)
await client.list('""', '"%"') # Get mail folders
await client.select('INBOX') # always raises asyncio.TimeoutError

If I don't pass the proxy, all methods, like select, work fine. What am I doing wrong?

So what happens when you do pass the proxy?  Do you get an error? A traceback?  A hang?  Dragons?

Yes, check at the last line of code: await client.select('INBOX') # always raises asyncio.TimeoutError
